# Magento: How to change image size with $imgSize

Tags: php, magento, resize, magento-1.7, image-resizing

i am trying to change the image size in magento category view and i am trying to edit the following file.

template/catalog/product/list.phtml

I want different height and width for image dont want a square image....

```
enter code here
 <?php 

    $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 

    if($_columnCount == 4){
        $imgSize = 155;
    }elseif($_columnCount == 3){
        $imgSize = 245;
    }

?>
```

I am using 3 columns count so 245 imagesize matters here,but how to change it. I want different height and different width.For example use width=200 and height=300.

Thanks in advance
Usman

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
<?php 
  $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 
  if( $_columnCount == 4 ) {
    $imgSizeWidth = 200;
    $imgSizeHeight = 300;
  } elseif( $_columnCount == 3 ) {
    $imgSizeWidth = 500;
    $imgSizeHeight = 800;
  }
?>

<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepAspectRatio(false)->resize($imgSizeWidth, $imgSizeHeight); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```

Comment: I put your code by changing resize($imgSizeWidth, $imgSizeHeight); to resize($200, $300); but syntax error. i removed $imgSize = 245; and put your code in its place...Its not working is there any other way around or i am implementing it wrong...

Comment: I've added your example in and modify it. Please learn some PHP basics before posting questions about Magento or you will have pretty hard times customizing it.

Comment: <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
  <?php 
  $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); 
  if( $_columnCount == 4 ) {
    $imgSizeWidth = 200;
    $imgSizeHeight = 300;
  } elseif( $_columnCount == 3 ) {
    $imgSizeWidth = 200;
    $imgSizeHeight = 300;
  }
?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepAspectRatio(false)->resize($imgSizeWidth, $imgSizeHeight); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
    ?> image not showing up

Comment: Image is not showing up.i have pasted the code here. Actually i always get hints from google but this time i cant find anything about $imgsize